# .htaccess redirect of a url that has brackets

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URL:

```
http://www.suplementospt.com/Goldnutrition-Pack-3x-Mega-Cla-(Portes-Gratis)
```

and I need to redirect it to

```
http://www.suplementospt.com/Goldnutrition-Pack-3x-Mega-Cla
```

Its not working and I think the problem are the brackets.

My code:

```
RewriteRule ^Goldnutrition-Pack-3x-Mega-Cla-(Portes-Gratis)?$ http://www.suplementospt.com/Goldnutrition-Pack-3x-Mega-Cla [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since .htaccess uses RegEx to match URLs and parentheses are RegEx special characters, you need to escape them:

```
RewriteRule ^Goldnutrition-Pack-3x-Mega-Cla-\(Portes-Gratis\)$ http://www.suplementospt.com/Goldnutrition-Pack-3x-Mega-Cla [R=301,L]
```

Also, don't forget to enable the rewrite engine by placing the following code at the top of your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: Aren't grouping parentheses needed around the escaped ones to facilitate optional matching? As your current regex stands, the only character with optional matching is the final escaped parenthesis. What about this: `(\(foo\))?`.

Comment: @jreut Grouping parentheses would be needed if he wanted the part in parentheses to be optional, but from the question, I don't see that he wants that. I don't know why the question mark is there though. (I'll remove it for now.) If he wanted the the parentheses and their contents to be optional, the only difference from the resulting URL would be the trailing hyphen.

Comment: I was confused as well as to why the OP would need optional matching, but I was just making sure. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask about is not so much `.htaccess` specific but about so called *Regular Expressions*, or more specific the *flavor* of *Regular Expressions* used in the [`mod_rewrite` Apache Extensions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

You find [these *Regular Expressions*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) explained there and right as you assume, the brackets are special characters.

They have a special meaning (grouping) and therefore can not be used just "as-is" (verbatim) but need to be *escaped*. This is done by prefixing a character with a special meaning (like `(` or `)`) with `\` which gives back the "character" meaning to it:

```
RewriteRule ^Goldnutrition-Pack-3x-Mega-Cla-\(Portes-Gratis\)?$ ...
```

I hope this explanation and links help you a bit to write all those regexes in rewrite-rules you'll need.